# Looking for something similar to this dropline menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I have searched high and low looking for a menu like the one at the following site:

[www.ultragraph.co.uk](http://www.ultragraph.co.uk)

All i can find is simple dropline menu's. Does anyone know where i might be able to find one similar to the one on ultragraph.co.uk? I'm basically trying to find one where the sub-menu is hidden and reveals on mouseover.

Thanks in advance,

Lee

Comment: you can get this menu here<br/>[dynamicdrive.com](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/jquery_drop_line_menu/)

Comment: Also, DynamicDrive is worse than W3Schools.

Answer (score 1):

That specific "[dropline menu](http://www.google.com/search?q=dropline+menu)" comes bundled with a [Joomla template called Tachyon](http://demo.rockettheme.com/feb11/tutorials/menu-options?menu-type=splicemenu).

Comment: +1 for being the only one to get it exactly right :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a "[lava lamp menu](http://www.queness.com/resources/html/lava/index.html)". [Here](http://www.queness.com/post/530/simple-lava-lamp-menu-tutorial-with-jquery) is a tutorial how to build one. And [this](http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/23/lavalamp-for-jquery-lovers/) is a jQuery plugin ready for use.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response..... looks good. How would i then add the reveal div aspect and the other level of the menu?>